# How to hide textbox in windows phone sdk

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

Currently i am trying to make my first app for windows phone using windows phone 7.1 sdk. I have installed  and i have started making my app. In my app i have to hide a textbox and textblock when an user select a specific radiobutton. I have used below code to hide text box

```
Private Sub Radio1_Checked(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles Radio1.Checked

    textbox1.Visible = true
    textbox2.Visible = false

    End Sub
```

But I am getting this error

```
'Visible' is not a member of 'System.Windows.Controls.TextBox'.
```

I have good a experience in visual basic but i am new to windows phone sdk and c sharp

advance thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft MSDN TextBox UI Element](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx)

The property to control the visibility is called `Visibility`.

Therefore:

```
textbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
textbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
textbox1.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```